# Mouse Over an image to get the color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
 <img src="../../images/fillpaint3.png" id="fillpaint" alt="fill paint">
```

I am only able to display the color picker through clicking of a text field [image]

I want to display the color picker after clicking the image not the text box. Any idea how can i do it?

Jquery

```
var jscolor = {

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
    for(var i=0; i<e.length; i+=1) {
        if(e[i].href) { base = e[i].href; }
    }

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i=0; i<e.length; i+=1) {
        if(e[i].src && /(^|\/)jscolor\.js([?#].*)?$/i.test(e[i].src)) {
            var src = new jscolor.URI(e[i].src);
            var srcAbs = src.toAbsolute(base);
            srcAbs.path = srcAbs.path.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ''); // remove filename
            srcAbs.query = null;
            srcAbs.fragment = null;
            return srcAbs.toString();
        }
    }
    return false;
},


bind : function() {
    var matchClass = new RegExp('(^|\\s)('+jscolor.bindClass+')(\\s*(\\{[^}]*\\})|\\s|$)', 'i');
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<e.length; i+=1) {
        if(jscolor.isColorAttrSupported && e[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'color') {
            // skip inputs of type 'color' if the browser supports this feature
            continue;
        }
        var m;
        if(!e[i].color && e[i].className && (m = e[i].className.match(matchClass))) {
            var prop = {};
            if(m[4]) {
                try {
                    prop = (new Function ('return (' + m[4] + ')'))();
                } catch(eInvalidProp) {}
            }
            e[i].color = new jscolor.color(e[i], prop);
        }
    }
},


preload : function() {
    for(var fn in jscolor.imgRequire) {
        if(jscolor.imgRequire.hasOwnProperty(fn)) {
            jscolor.loadImage(fn);
        }
    }
},


images : {
    pad : [ 181, 101 ],
    sld : [ 16, 101 ],
    cross : [ 15, 15 ],
    arrow : [ 7, 11 ]
},


imgRequire : {},
imgLoaded : {},


requireImage : function(filename) {
    jscolor.imgRequire[filename] = true;
},


loadImage : function(filename) {
    if(!jscolor.imgLoaded[filename]) {
        jscolor.imgLoaded[filename] = new Image();
        jscolor.imgLoaded[filename].src = jscolor.getDir()+filename;
    }
},


fetchElement : function(mixed) {
    return typeof mixed === 'string' ? document.getElementById(mixed) : mixed;
},


addEvent : function(el, evnt, func) {
    if(el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
    } else if(el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on'+evnt, func);
    }
},


fireEvent : function(el, evnt) {
    if(!el) {
        return;
    }
    if(document.createEvent) {
        var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        ev.initEvent(evnt, true, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    } else if(document.createEventObject) {
        var ev = document.createEventObject();
        el.fireEvent('on'+evnt, ev);
    } else if(el['on'+evnt]) { // alternatively use the traditional event model (IE5)
        el['on'+evnt]();
    }
},


getElementPos : function(e) {
    var e1=e, e2=e;
    var x=0, y=0;
    if(e1.offsetParent) {
        do {
            x += e1.offsetLeft;
            y += e1.offsetTop;
        } while(e1 = e1.offsetParent);
    }
    while((e2 = e2.parentNode) && e2.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'BODY') {
        x -= e2.scrollLeft;
        y -= e2.scrollTop;
    }
    return [x, y];
},


getElementSize : function(e) {
    return [e.offsetWidth, e.offsetHeight];
},


getRelMousePos : function(e) {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (!e) { e = window.event; }
    if (typeof e.offsetX === 'number') {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
    } else if (typeof e.layerX === 'number') {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
},


getViewPos : function() {
    if(typeof window.pageYOffset === 'number') {
        return [window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset];
    } else if(document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
        return [document.body.scrollLeft, document.body.scrollTop];
    } else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
        return [document.documentElement.scrollLeft, document.documentElement.scrollTop];
    } else {
        return [0, 0];
    }
},


getViewSize : function() {
    if(typeof window.innerWidth === 'number') {
        return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    } else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        return [document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight];
    } else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        return [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];
    } else {
        return [0, 0];
    }
},


URI : function(uri) { // See RFC3986

    this.scheme = null;
    this.authority = null;
    this.path = '';
    this.query = null;
    this.fragment = null;

    this.parse = function(uri) {
        var m = uri.match(/^(([A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z+.-]*)(:))?((\/\/)([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)((\?)([^#]*))?((#)(.*))?/);
        this.scheme = m[3] ? m[2] : null;
        this.authority = m[5] ? m[6] : null;
        this.path = m[7];
        this.query = m[9] ? m[10] : null;
        this.fragment = m[12] ? m[13] : null;
        return this;
    };

    this.toString = function() {
        var result = '';
        if(this.scheme !== null) { result = result + this.scheme + ':'; }
        if(this.authority !== null) { result = result + '//' + this.authority; }
        if(this.path !== null) { result = result + this.path; }
        if(this.query !== null) { result = result + '?' + this.query; }
        if(this.fragment !== null) { result = result + '#' + this.fragment; }
        return result;
    };

    this.toAbsolute = function(base) {
        var base = new jscolor.URI(base);
        var r = this;
        var t = new jscolor.URI;

        if(base.scheme === null) { return false; }

        if(r.scheme !== null && r.scheme.toLowerCase() === base.scheme.toLowerCase()) {
            r.scheme = null;
        }

        if(r.scheme !== null) {
            t.scheme = r.scheme;
            t.authority = r.authority;
            t.path = removeDotSegments(r.path);
            t.query = r.query;
        } else {
            if(r.authority !== null) {
                t.authority = r.authority;
                t.path = removeDotSegments(r.path);
                t.query = r.query;
            } else {
                if(r.path === '') {
                    t.path = base.path;
                    if(r.query !== null) {
                        t.query = r.query;
                    } else {
                        t.query = base.query;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(r.path.substr(0,1) === '/') {
                        t.path = removeDotSegments(r.path);
                    } else {
                        if(base.authority !== null && base.path === '') {
                            t.path = '/'+r.path;
                        } else {
                            t.path = base.path.replace(/[^\/]+$/,'')+r.path;
                        }
                        t.path = removeDotSegments(t.path);
                    }
                    t.query = r.query;
                }
                t.authority = base.authority;
            }
            t.scheme = base.scheme;
        }
        t.fragment = r.fragment;

        return t;
    };

    function removeDotSegments(path) {
        var out = '';
        while(path) {
            if(path.substr(0,3)==='../' || path.substr(0,2)==='./') {
                path = path.replace(/^\.+/,'').substr(1);
            } else if(path.substr(0,3)==='/./' || path==='/.') {
                path = '/'+path.substr(3);
            } else if(path.substr(0,4)==='/../' || path==='/..') {
                path = '/'+path.substr(4);
                out = out.replace(/\/?[^\/]*$/, '');
            } else if(path==='.' || path==='..') {
                path = '';
            } else {
                var rm = path.match(/^\/?[^\/]*/)[0];
                path = path.substr(rm.length);
                out = out + rm;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    if(uri) {
        this.parse(uri);
    }

},


//
// Usage example:
// var myColor = new jscolor.color(myInputElement)
//

color : function(target, prop) {


    this.required = true; // refuse empty values?
    this.adjust = true; // adjust value to uniform notation?
    this.hash = false; // prefix color with # symbol?
    this.caps = true; // uppercase?
    this.slider = true; // show the value/saturation slider?
    this.valueElement = target; // value holder
    this.styleElement = target; // where to reflect current color
    this.onImmediateChange = null; // onchange callback (can be either string or function)
    this.hsv = [0, 0, 1]; // read-only  0-6, 0-1, 0-1
    this.rgb = [1, 1, 1]; // read-only  0-1, 0-1, 0-1
    this.minH = 0; // read-only  0-6
    this.maxH = 6; // read-only  0-6
    this.minS = 0; // read-only  0-1
    this.maxS = 1; // read-only  0-1
    this.minV = 0; // read-only  0-1
    this.maxV = 1; // read-only  0-1

    this.pickerOnfocus = true; // display picker on focus?
    this.pickerMode = 'HSV'; // HSV | HVS
    this.pickerPosition = 'bottom'; // left | right | top | bottom
    this.pickerSmartPosition = true; // automatically adjust picker position when necessary
    this.pickerFixedPosition = false; // set to true to stop picker from moving on scroll
    this.pickerButtonHeight = 20; // px
    this.pickerClosable = false;
    this.pickerCloseText = 'Close';
    this.pickerButtonColor = 'ButtonText'; // px
    this.pickerFace = 10; // px
    this.pickerFaceColor = 'ThreeDFace'; // CSS color
    this.pickerBorder = 1; // px
    this.pickerBorderColor = 'ThreeDHighlight ThreeDShadow ThreeDShadow ThreeDHighlight'; // CSS color
    this.pickerInset = 1; // px
    this.pickerInsetColor = 'ThreeDShadow ThreeDHighlight ThreeDHighlight ThreeDShadow'; // CSS color
    this.pickerZIndex = 10000;


    for(var p in prop) {
        if(prop.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            this[p] = prop[p];
        }
    }


    this.hidePicker = function() {
        if(isPickerOwner()) {
            removePicker();
        }
    };


    this.showPicker = function() {
        if(!isPickerOwner()) {
            var tp = jscolor.getElementPos(target); // target pos
            var ts = jscolor.getElementSize(target); // target size
            var vp = jscolor.getViewPos(); // view pos
            var vs = jscolor.getViewSize(); // view size
            var ps = getPickerDims(this); // picker size
            var a, b, c;
            switch(this.pickerPosition.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'left': a=1; b=0; c=-1; break;
                case 'right':a=1; b=0; c=1; break;
                case 'top':  a=0; b=1; c=-1; break;
                default:     a=0; b=1; c=1; break;
            }
            var l = (ts[b]+ps[b])/2;

            // picker pos
            if (!this.pickerSmartPosition) {
                var pp = [
                    tp[a],
                    tp[b]+ts[b]-l+l*c
                ];
            } else {
                var pp = [
                    -vp[a]+tp[a]+ps[a] > vs[a] ?
                        (-vp[a]+tp[a]+ts[a]/2 > vs[a]/2 && tp[a]+ts[a]-ps[a] >= 0 ? tp[a]+ts[a]-ps[a] : tp[a]) :
                        tp[a],
                    -vp[b]+tp[b]+ts[b]+ps[b]-l+l*c > vs[b] ?
                        (-vp[b]+tp[b]+ts[b]/2 > vs[b]/2 && tp[b]+ts[b]-l-l*c >= 0 ? tp[b]+ts[b]-l-l*c : tp[b]+ts[b]-l+l*c) :
                        (tp[b]+ts[b]-l+l*c >= 0 ? tp[b]+ts[b]-l+l*c : tp[b]+ts[b]-l-l*c)
                ];
            }
            drawPicker(pp[a], pp[b]);
        }
    };


    this.importColor = function() {
        if(!valueElement) {
            this.exportColor();
        } else {
            if(!this.adjust) {
                if(!this.fromString(valueElement.value, leaveValue)) {
                    styleElement.style.backgroundImage = styleElement.jscStyle.backgroundImage;
                    styleElement.style.backgroundColor = styleElement.jscStyle.backgroundColor;
                    styleElement.style.color = styleElement.jscStyle.color;
                    this.exportColor(leaveValue | leaveStyle);
                }
            } else if(!this.required && /^\s*$/.test(valueElement.value)) {
                valueElement.value = '';
                styleElement.style.backgroundImage = styleElement.jscStyle.backgroundImage;
                styleElement.style.backgroundColor = styleElement.jscStyle.backgroundColor;
                styleElement.style.color = styleElement.jscStyle.color;
                this.exportColor(leaveValue | leaveStyle);

            } else if(this.fromString(valueElement.value)) {
                // OK
            } else {
                this.exportColor();
            }
        }
    };


    this.exportColor = function(flags) {
        if(!(flags & leaveValue) && valueElement) {
            var value = this.toString();
            if(this.caps) { value = value.toUpperCase(); }
            if(this.hash) { value = '#'+value; }
            valueElement.value = value;
        }
        if(!(flags & leaveStyle) && styleElement) {
            styleElement.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            styleElement.style.backgroundColor =
                '#'+this.toString();
            styleElement.style.color =
                0.213 * this.rgb[0] +
                0.715 * this.rgb[1] +
                0.072 * this.rgb[2]
                < 0.5 ? '#FFF' : '#000';
        }
        if(!(flags & leavePad) && isPickerOwner()) {
            redrawPad();
        }
        if(!(flags & leaveSld) && isPickerOwner()) {
            redrawSld();
        }
    };


    this.fromHSV = function(h, s, v, flags) { // null = don't change
        if(h !== null) { h = Math.max(0.0, this.minH, Math.min(6.0, this.maxH, h)); }
        if(s !== null) { s = Math.max(0.0, this.minS, Math.min(1.0, this.maxS, s)); }
        if(v !== null) { v = Math.max(0.0, this.minV, Math.min(1.0, this.maxV, v)); }

        this.rgb = HSV_RGB(
            h===null ? this.hsv[0] : (this.hsv[0]=h),
            s===null ? this.hsv[1] : (this.hsv[1]=s),
            v===null ? this.hsv[2] : (this.hsv[2]=v)
        );

        this.exportColor(flags);
    };


    this.fromRGB = function(r, g, b, flags) { // null = don't change
        if(r !== null) { r = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, r)); }
        if(g !== null) { g = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, g)); }
        if(b !== null) { b = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, b)); }

        var hsv = RGB_HSV(
            r===null ? this.rgb[0] : r,
            g===null ? this.rgb[1] : g,
            b===null ? this.rgb[2] : b
        );
        if(hsv[0] !== null) {
            this.hsv[0] = Math.max(0.0, this.minH, Math.min(6.0, this.maxH, hsv[0]));
        }
        if(hsv[2] !== 0) {
            this.hsv[1] = hsv[1]===null ? null : Math.max(0.0, this.minS, Math.min(1.0, this.maxS, hsv[1]));
        }
        this.hsv[2] = hsv[2]===null ? null : Math.max(0.0, this.minV, Math.min(1.0, this.maxV, hsv[2]));

        // update RGB according to final HSV, as some values might be trimmed
        var rgb = HSV_RGB(this.hsv[0], this.hsv[1], this.hsv[2]);
        this.rgb[0] = rgb[0];
        this.rgb[1] = rgb[1];
        this.rgb[2] = rgb[2];

        this.exportColor(flags);
    };


    this.fromString = function(hex, flags) {
        var m = hex.match(/^\W*([0-9A-F]{3}([0-9A-F]{3})?)\W*$/i);
        if(!m) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if(m[1].length === 6) { // 6-char notation
                this.fromRGB(
                    parseInt(m[1].substr(0,2),16) / 255,
                    parseInt(m[1].substr(2,2),16) / 255,
                    parseInt(m[1].substr(4,2),16) / 255,
                    flags
                );
            } else { // 3-char notation
                this.fromRGB(
                    parseInt(m[1].charAt(0)+m[1].charAt(0),16) / 255,
                    parseInt(m[1].charAt(1)+m[1].charAt(1),16) / 255,
                    parseInt(m[1].charAt(2)+m[1].charAt(2),16) / 255,
                    flags
                );
            }
            return true;
        }
    };


    this.toString = function() {
        return (
            (0x100 | Math.round(255*this.rgb[0])).toString(16).substr(1) +
            (0x100 | Math.round(255*this.rgb[1])).toString(16).substr(1) +
            (0x100 | Math.round(255*this.rgb[2])).toString(16).substr(1)
        );
    };


    function RGB_HSV(r, g, b) {
        var n = Math.min(Math.min(r,g),b);
        var v = Math.max(Math.max(r,g),b);
        var m = v - n;
        if(m === 0) { return [ null, 0, v ]; }
        var h = r===n ? 3+(b-g)/m : (g===n ? 5+(r-b)/m : 1+(g-r)/m);
        return [ h===6?0:h, m/v, v ];
    }


    function HSV_RGB(h, s, v) {
        if(h === null) { return [ v, v, v ]; }
        var i = Math.floor(h);
        var f = i%2 ? h-i : 1-(h-i);
        var m = v * (1 - s);
        var n = v * (1 - s*f);
        switch(i) {
            case 6:
            case 0: return [v,n,m];
            case 1: return [n,v,m];
            case 2: return [m,v,n];
            case 3: return [m,n,v];
            case 4: return [n,m,v];
            case 5: return [v,m,n];
        }
    }


    function removePicker() {
        delete jscolor.picker.owner;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(jscolor.picker.boxB);
    }


    function drawPicker(x, y) {
        if(!jscolor.picker) {
            jscolor.picker = {
                box : document.createElement('div'),
                boxB : document.createElement('div'),
                pad : document.createElement('div'),
                padB : document.createElement('div'),
                padM : document.createElement('div'),
                sld : document.createElement('div'),
                sldB : document.createElement('div'),
                sldM : document.createElement('div'),
                btn : document.createElement('div'),
                btnS : document.createElement('span'),
                btnT : document.createTextNode(THIS.pickerCloseText)
            };
            for(var i=0,segSize=4; i<jscolor.images.sld[1]; i+=segSize) {
                var seg = document.createElement('div');
                seg.style.height = segSize+'px';
                seg.style.fontSize = '1px';
                seg.style.lineHeight = '0';
                jscolor.picker.sld.appendChild(seg);
            }
            jscolor.picker.sldB.appendChild(jscolor.picker.sld);
            jscolor.picker.box.appendChild(jscolor.picker.sldB);
            jscolor.picker.box.appendChild(jscolor.picker.sldM);
            jscolor.picker.padB.appendChild(jscolor.picker.pad);
            jscolor.picker.box.appendChild(jscolor.picker.padB);
            jscolor.picker.box.appendChild(jscolor.picker.padM);
            jscolor.picker.btnS.appendChild(jscolor.picker.btnT);
            jscolor.picker.btn.appendChild(jscolor.picker.btnS);
            jscolor.picker.box.appendChild(jscolor.picker.btn);
            jscolor.picker.boxB.appendChild(jscolor.picker.box);
        }

        var p = jscolor.picker;

        // controls interaction
        p.box.onmouseup =
        p.box.onmouseout = function() { target.focus(); };
        p.box.onmousedown = function() { abortBlur=true; };
        p.box.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (holdPad || holdSld) {
                holdPad && setPad(e);
                holdSld && setSld(e);
                if (document.selection) {
                    document.selection.empty();
                } else if (window.getSelection) {
                    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                }
                dispatchImmediateChange();
            }
        };
        if('ontouchstart' in window) { // if touch device
            var handle_touchmove = function(e) {
                var event={
                    'offsetX': e.touches[0].pageX-touchOffset.X,
                    'offsetY': e.touches[0].pageY-touchOffset.Y
                };
                if (holdPad || holdSld) {
                    holdPad && setPad(event);
                    holdSld && setSld(event);
                    dispatchImmediateChange();
                }
                e.stopPropagation(); // prevent move "view" on broswer
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent Default - Android Fix (else android generated only 1-2 touchmove events)
            };
            p.box.removeEventListener('touchmove', handle_touchmove, false)
            p.box.addEventListener('touchmove', handle_touchmove, false)
        }
        p.padM.onmouseup =
        p.padM.onmouseout = function() { if(holdPad) { holdPad=false; jscolor.fireEvent(valueElement,'change'); } };
        p.padM.onmousedown = function(e) {
            // if the slider is at the bottom, move it up
            switch(modeID) {
                case 0: if (THIS.hsv[2] === 0) { THIS.fromHSV(null, null, 1.0); }; break;
                case 1: if (THIS.hsv[1] === 0) { THIS.fromHSV(null, 1.0, null); }; break;
            }
            holdSld=false;
            holdPad=true;
            setPad(e);
            dispatchImmediateChange();
        };
        if('ontouchstart' in window) {
            p.padM.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                touchOffset={
                    'X': e.target.offsetParent.offsetLeft,
                    'Y': e.target.offsetParent.offsetTop
                };
                this.onmousedown({
                    'offsetX':e.touches[0].pageX-touchOffset.X,
                    'offsetY':e.touches[0].pageY-touchOffset.Y
                });
            });
        }
        p.sldM.onmouseup =
        p.sldM.onmouseout = function() { if(holdSld) { holdSld=false; jscolor.fireEvent(valueElement,'change'); } };
        p.sldM.onmousedown = function(e) {
            holdPad=false;
            holdSld=true;
            setSld(e);
            dispatchImmediateChange();
        };
        if('ontouchstart' in window) {
            p.sldM.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                touchOffset={
                    'X': e.target.offsetParent.offsetLeft,
                    'Y': e.target.offsetParent.offsetTop
                };
                this.onmousedown({
                    'offsetX':e.touches[0].pageX-touchOffset.X,
                    'offsetY':e.touches[0].pageY-touchOffset.Y
                });
            });
        }

        // picker
        var dims = getPickerDims(THIS);
        p.box.style.width = dims[0] + 'px';
        p.box.style.height = dims[1] + 'px';

        // picker border
        p.boxB.style.position = THIS.pickerFixedPosition ? 'fixed' : 'absolute';
        p.boxB.style.clear = 'both';
        p.boxB.style.left = x+'px';
        p.boxB.style.top = y+'px';
        p.boxB.style.zIndex = THIS.pickerZIndex;
        p.boxB.style.border = THIS.pickerBorder+'px solid';
        p.boxB.style.borderColor = THIS.pickerBorderColor;
        p.boxB.style.background = THIS.pickerFaceColor;

        // pad image
        p.pad.style.width = jscolor.images.pad[0]+'px';
        p.pad.style.height = jscolor.images.pad[1]+'px';

        // pad border
        p.padB.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.padB.style.left = THIS.pickerFace+'px';
        p.padB.style.top = THIS.pickerFace+'px';
        p.padB.style.border = THIS.pickerInset+'px solid';
        p.padB.style.borderColor = THIS.pickerInsetColor;

        // pad mouse area
        p.padM.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.padM.style.left = '0';
        p.padM.style.top = '0';
        p.padM.style.width = THIS.pickerFace + 2*THIS.pickerInset + jscolor.images.pad[0] + jscolor.images.arrow[0] + 'px';
        p.padM.style.height = p.box.style.height;
        p.padM.style.cursor = 'crosshair';

        // slider image
        p.sld.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        p.sld.style.width = jscolor.images.sld[0]+'px';
        p.sld.style.height = jscolor.images.sld[1]+'px';

        // slider border
        p.sldB.style.display = THIS.slider ? 'block' : 'none';
        p.sldB.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.sldB.style.right = THIS.pickerFace+'px';
        p.sldB.style.top = THIS.pickerFace+'px';
        p.sldB.style.border = THIS.pickerInset+'px solid';
        p.sldB.style.borderColor = THIS.pickerInsetColor;

        // slider mouse area
        p.sldM.style.display = THIS.slider ? 'block' : 'none';
        p.sldM.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.sldM.style.right = '0';
        p.sldM.style.top = '0';
        p.sldM.style.width = jscolor.images.sld[0] + jscolor.images.arrow[0] + THIS.pickerFace + 2*THIS.pickerInset + 'px';
        p.sldM.style.height = p.box.style.height;
        try {
            p.sldM.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        } catch(eOldIE) {
            p.sldM.style.cursor = 'hand';
        }

        // "close" button
        function setBtnBorder() {
            var insetColors = THIS.pickerInsetColor.split(/\s+/);
            var pickerOutsetColor = insetColors.length < 2 ? insetColors[0] : insetColors[1] + ' ' + insetColors[0] + ' ' + insetColors[0] + ' ' + insetColors[1];
            p.btn.style.borderColor = pickerOutsetColor;
        }
        p.btn.style.display = THIS.pickerClosable ? 'block' : 'none';
        p.btn.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.btn.style.left = THIS.pickerFace + 'px';
        p.btn.style.bottom = THIS.pickerFace + 'px';
        p.btn.style.padding = '0 15px';
        p.btn.style.height = '18px';
        p.btn.style.border = THIS.pickerInset + 'px solid';
        setBtnBorder();
        p.btn.style.color = THIS.pickerButtonColor;
        p.btn.style.font = '12px sans-serif';
        p.btn.style.textAlign = 'center';
        try {
            p.btn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        } catch(eOldIE) {
            p.btn.style.cursor = 'hand';
        }
        p.btn.onmousedown = function () {
            THIS.hidePicker();
        };
        p.btnS.style.lineHeight = p.btn.style.height;

        // load images in optimal order
        switch(modeID) {
            case 0: var padImg = 'hs.png'; break;
            case 1: var padImg = 'hv.png'; break;
        }
        p.padM.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+jscolor.getDir()+"cross.gif')";
        p.padM.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        p.sldM.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+jscolor.getDir()+"arrow.gif')";
        p.sldM.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        p.pad.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+jscolor.getDir()+padImg+"')";
        p.pad.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        p.pad.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";

        // place pointers
        redrawPad();
        redrawSld();

        jscolor.picker.owner = THIS;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(p.boxB);
    }


    function getPickerDims(o) {
        var dims = [
            2*o.pickerInset + 2*o.pickerFace + jscolor.images.pad[0] +
                (o.slider ? 2*o.pickerInset + 2*jscolor.images.arrow[0] + jscolor.images.sld[0] : 0),
            o.pickerClosable ?
                4*o.pickerInset + 3*o.pickerFace + jscolor.images.pad[1] + o.pickerButtonHeight :
                2*o.pickerInset + 2*o.pickerFace + jscolor.images.pad[1]
        ];
        return dims;
    }


    function redrawPad() {
        // redraw the pad pointer
        switch(modeID) {
            case 0: var yComponent = 1; break;
            case 1: var yComponent = 2; break;
        }
        var x = Math.round((THIS.hsv[0]/6) * (jscolor.images.pad[0]-1));
        var y = Math.round((1-THIS.hsv[yComponent]) * (jscolor.images.pad[1]-1));
        jscolor.picker.padM.style.backgroundPosition =
            (THIS.pickerFace+THIS.pickerInset+x - Math.floor(jscolor.images.cross[0]/2)) + 'px ' +
            (THIS.pickerFace+THIS.pickerInset+y - Math.floor(jscolor.images.cross[1]/2)) + 'px';

        // redraw the slider image
        var seg = jscolor.picker.sld.childNodes;

        switch(modeID) {
            case 0:
                var rgb = HSV_RGB(THIS.hsv[0], THIS.hsv[1], 1);
                for(var i=0; i<seg.length; i+=1) {
                    seg[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+
                        (rgb[0]*(1-i/seg.length)*100)+'%,'+
                        (rgb[1]*(1-i/seg.length)*100)+'%,'+
                        (rgb[2]*(1-i/seg.length)*100)+'%)';
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                var rgb, s, c = [ THIS.hsv[2], 0, 0 ];
                var i = Math.floor(THIS.hsv[0]);
                var f = i%2 ? THIS.hsv[0]-i : 1-(THIS.hsv[0]-i);
                switch(i) {
                    case 6:
                    case 0: rgb=[0,1,2]; break;
                    case 1: rgb=[1,0,2]; break;
                    case 2: rgb=[2,0,1]; break;
                    case 3: rgb=[2,1,0]; break;
                    case 4: rgb=[1,2,0]; break;
                    case 5: rgb=[0,2,1]; break;
                }
                for(var i=0; i<seg.length; i+=1) {
                    s = 1 - 1/(seg.length-1)*i;
                    c[1] = c[0] * (1 - s*f);
                    c[2] = c[0] * (1 - s);
                    seg[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+
                        (c[rgb[0]]*100)+'%,'+
                        (c[rgb[1]]*100)+'%,'+
                        (c[rgb[2]]*100)+'%)';
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    function redrawSld() {
        // redraw the slider pointer
        switch(modeID) {
            case 0: var yComponent = 2; break;
            case 1: var yComponent = 1; break;
        }
        var y = Math.round((1-THIS.hsv[yComponent]) * (jscolor.images.sld[1]-1));
        jscolor.picker.sldM.style.backgroundPosition =
            '0 ' + (THIS.pickerFace+THIS.pickerInset+y - Math.floor(jscolor.images.arrow[1]/2)) + 'px';
    }


    function isPickerOwner() {
        return jscolor.picker && jscolor.picker.owner === THIS;
    }


    function blurTarget() {
        if(valueElement === target) {
            THIS.importColor();
        }
        if(THIS.pickerOnfocus) {
            THIS.hidePicker();
        }
    }


    function blurValue() {
        if(valueElement !== target) {
            THIS.importColor();
        }
    }


    function setPad(e) {
        var mpos = jscolor.getRelMousePos(e);
        var x = mpos.x - THIS.pickerFace - THIS.pickerInset;
        var y = mpos.y - THIS.pickerFace - THIS.pickerInset;
        switch(modeID) {
            case 0: THIS.fromHSV(x*(6/(jscolor.images.pad[0]-1)), 1 - y/(jscolor.images.pad[1]-1), null, leaveSld); break;
            case 1: THIS.fromHSV(x*(6/(jscolor.images.pad[0]-1)), null, 1 - y/(jscolor.images.pad[1]-1), leaveSld); break;
        }
    }


    function setSld(e) {
        var mpos = jscolor.getRelMousePos(e);
        var y = mpos.y - THIS.pickerFace - THIS.pickerInset;
        switch(modeID) {
            case 0: THIS.fromHSV(null, null, 1 - y/(jscolor.images.sld[1]-1), leavePad); break;
            case 1: THIS.fromHSV(null, 1 - y/(jscolor.images.sld[1]-1), null, leavePad); break;
        }
    }


    function dispatchImmediateChange() {
        if (THIS.onImmediateChange) {
            var callback;
            if (typeof THIS.onImmediateChange === 'string') {
                callback = new Function (THIS.onImmediateChange);
            } else {
                callback = THIS.onImmediateChange;
            }
            callback.call(THIS);
        }
    }


    var THIS = this;
    var modeID = this.pickerMode.toLowerCase()==='hvs' ? 1 : 0;
    var abortBlur = false;
    var
        valueElement = jscolor.fetchElement(this.valueElement),
        styleElement = jscolor.fetchElement(this.styleElement);
    var
        holdPad = false,
        holdSld = false,
        touchOffset = {};
    var
        leaveValue = 1<<0,
        leaveStyle = 1<<1,
        leavePad = 1<<2,
        leaveSld = 1<<3;

    jscolor.isColorAttrSupported = false;
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    if(el.setAttribute) {
        el.setAttribute('type', 'color');
        if(el.type.toLowerCase() == 'color') {
            jscolor.isColorAttrSupported = true;
        }
    }

    // target
    jscolor.addEvent(target, 'focus', function() {
        if(THIS.pickerOnfocus) { THIS.showPicker(); }
    });
    jscolor.addEvent(target, 'blur', function() {
        if(!abortBlur) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){ abortBlur || blurTarget(); abortBlur=false; }, 0);
        } else {
            abortBlur = false;
        }
    });

    // valueElement
    if(valueElement) {
        var updateField = function() {
            THIS.fromString(valueElement.value, leaveValue);
            dispatchImmediateChange();
        };
        jscolor.addEvent(valueElement, 'keyup', updateField);
        jscolor.addEvent(valueElement, 'input', updateField);
        jscolor.addEvent(valueElement, 'blur', blurValue);
        valueElement.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    }

    // styleElement
    if(styleElement) {
        styleElement.jscStyle = {
            backgroundImage : styleElement.style.backgroundImage,
            backgroundColor : styleElement.style.backgroundColor,
            color : styleElement.style.color
        };
    }

    // require images
    switch(modeID) {
        case 0: jscolor.requireImage('hs.png'); break;
        case 1: jscolor.requireImage('hv.png'); break;
    }
    jscolor.requireImage('cross.gif');
    jscolor.requireImage('arrow.gif');

    this.importColor();
}

};


 jscolor.install();
```

Please take a look at my jquery. Not all are here, stackoverflow dont allow me to insert everything

Comment: Which plugin are you using for the colorpicker?

Comment: Sorry to say that but this question is totally not answerable since you didn't provide enough information. Post the part of your jQuery code that displays the picker and we might be able to tell you how to write "img" instead of  "input".

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Sorry i dont know which part it is. I had post the jquery

Comment: Why would you say you aren't using a plugin when it's plainly in the code? http://jscolor.com/

Comment: @fauxserious because i dont understand what you mean by plugin

Comment: Then instead of saying "No plugin" how about "What's a plugin?".

Comment: This seems to be the plugin code. Where's your integration code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the officially (I think that there is no officially way) but it's working.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onmouseenter = function() {
 document.querySelector('input')._jscLinkedInstance.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://jscolor.com/release/2.0/jscolor-2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>

Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567" tabindex="-1" />
<button>Open</button>
```

The `_jscLinkedInstance`object store the data of the plugin with properties and functions.

**Note:** This demo is for `mouseenter` event (for mouse-over requested in the title: `Mouse Over an image..`) If you want to trigger the `click` event of the image (button in the snippet) by your question (`I want to display the color picker after clicking the image`) just replace the `onmouseenter` with `onclick`.